# Jquery checkbox -show posts with checked tags

Tags: widgets, jquery, tags

Using jquery, How do I show a checkbox with the list of tags in the sidebar, and only show posts of the checked tag?

I cant seem to find this anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab and go, buddy! Had fun figuring this one out :)

- Create a file and upload to your plugins.
- Call list_ajax_tags() in theme where you want to display these tags.
- Modify to suit your needs

http://pastebin.com/3eZWEv5K

(had trouble formatting the code here)

Comment: @Jack You're welcome! One thing I forgot to go back and add was a conditional within the jQuery to only have one box checked at a time. Also the even currently fires whether you check or uncheck since it's just looking for the click and not the "checked" attribute. Anyway, if you need help with that too, let me know!

Comment: yeah yeah for sure. thanks so much, will let you know if i stumble into a problem.